# Как упростить код на php

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

есть рабочий метод, но чувствую что с точки зрения красоты кода это не правильно, как можно изменить код ?

```
public function getHighway($weight)
{
    if($weight <= 3) {
        $weightsum = $weight * 27;
    }elseif ($weight <= 6) {
        $weightsum = $weight * 35;
    }else{
        $weightsum = $weight * 55;
    }
    
    if ($weightsum < 5){
        $weightsum = 5;
    }
    
    if($weightsum > 500){
        $weightsum = 500;
    }
}
```

Comment: а что означают магические числа 3,6,5,500 ?)) ПОчему именно они? и почему дргие числа от них зависят? И почему именно эти числа зависят от первых?)

Comment: Ну это константы, вот так сложилось в коде что числа между собой зависимы)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский задача видимо такая. поэтому и числа таковы.

Comment: не вижу смысла что-либо тут менять, покуда ограничения только 3-6. Если каким-то образом этих пар станет больше, тогда можно думать. Пока что код прост и не велик, что хорошо. с точки зрения форматирования, это можно поджать, и части `return` не ясно, возвращать ли сумму.

Comment: На первый взгляд можно увидеть тут применение паттерна проектирования. Но чтобы точно сказать, надо всё понять что к чему)

Comment: У меня есть одно предложение пол улучшению. я бы добавил в эту функцию оператор return.

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу смысла тут ничего менять. Код прост и понятен. Можете, если позволяют правила оформления немного его ужать, но городить какие-либо другие конструкции тут смысла нет. Также, казалось бы, вернуть по итогу из метода надо `$weightsum`.

```
function x($weight){
     
      if($weight < 3)     $weight *= 27
      elseif($weight < 6) $weight *= 35
      else                $weight *= 55;

      if($weigth < 5)   return 5;
      if($weight > 500) return 500;

      return $weight;
}
```

но опять таки, "на вкус и цвет товарища нет".

Если вдруг вы пишите на php8, то возможно вас порадует оператор `match`, который потенциально превратит вашу функцию во что-то подобное ниженаписанному. При некотором увеличении числа констант, это будет нагляднее чем пытаться собрать условия в массив и писать код его обработки.

```
function x($w){
    
    $w = match(true){ 
             $w <= 3 => $w*27,
             $w <= 6 => $w*35,
             default => $w*55,
         };

      if($w < 5)   return 5;
      if($w > 500) return 500;

      return $w;

  }
```

прочие варианты, которые вы можете придумать могут выглядеть короче или еще как-то, но по факту плохо читаются, воспринимаются, не так наглядны и понятны как простой `if`

```
    // плохо - требует вообще понять, что происходит, 
    // малоэффектино ибо 2 вызова функции        
    return min(max($w, 5), 500);   

    // вложенный тернарный оператор - нечитаемая шляпа
    return $w < 5 ? 5 : 
           $w > 500 ? 500 : $w;
```

В общем стремитесь к простоте. Не надо усложнять то, где и так все наглядно.

Comment: Первый вариант нарушает RFC, а второй делает прямо противоположное запрошенному. я бы оставил только первую строчку в ответе

Comment: @Ипатьев RFC в смысле PSR ? на него молиться теперь надо что ли? А по второму - противоположное запрошенному это усложняет?, это да. но это вариант, который при некотором расширении числа констант 3-6-x-y-z будет нагляднее чем ifelse

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант предложу, раз пошли такие пляски:
[phpize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=db22a01a3d27a805a8e8a6e3bbf0ef1d&php_version=php7)

```
function getHighway($weight) {
    switch (true) {
        case $weight <= 3:
            $weightsum = $weight * 27;
            break;
        case $weight > 3 && $weight <= 6:
            $weightsum = $weight * 35;
            break;
        default:
            $weightsum = $weight * 55;
    }

    //пока не трогаем
    if ($weightsum < 5) {
        $weightsum = 5;
    }

    if ($weightsum > 500) {
        $weightsum = 500;
    }

    return $weightsum;
}

var_dump(getHighway(2));
var_dump(getHighway(5));
var_dump(getHighway(10));
//int 54
//int 175
//int 500
```